# finding proections with certain eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find a projection with following eigenvalues:

$\sigma$($\emptyset$)

$\sigma$(1)

$\sigma$(0)

I know that a shift matrix has no eigenvalues and that a zero matrix has the eigenvalue 0, but are these projections? I am struggling to find a projection that has only 1 as the eigenvalue.

Comment: What is your definition of "projection"? Assuming only $P^2=P$, the identity is the unique projection with only the eigenvalue $1$. I'm not sure I understand how a projection could have no eigenvalues, since *every* matrix has an eigenvalue. You have to go to infinite dimensions to find an operator with no eigenvalues.

Comment: P is a linear transformation P:V-->V and a projection such that P(P(x))=P(x) for any x in V.

Comment: As I understand, the shift operator does not have any eigenvalues.

Comment: Can you define the shift operator for me?

Comment: For the forward shift operator: T(z1, z2,...zn) = (0,z1,...zn-1). For the backward shift operator: T(z1, z2,...zn) = (z2, z3,...zn, 0). However, I see that this is not a projection such that P(P(x))=P(x), so it wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: That has an eigenvalue anyway: $T(0,0,\dots,1)=(0,0,0,\dots,0)$ for the forward shift, similar for the backward shift.